# Debug JBoss source code

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, maven, jboss

I would like to obtain the JBoss Application Server 5.1.0 source code to go through it on Debugging mode.
Where and how can I find the sources of JBoss? (if possible).

A Jar with the sources would be nice, but it seems not to be easy to find...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Either download the source from http://sourceforge.net/projects/jboss/files/JBoss/JBoss-5.1.0.GA/ or if you use Maven, you can use the `mvn dependency:sources` command.

Comment: Man, how did you find it? i am searching by JBoss in the main page and it doesn't appear (to do the same with other projects). By the way, thank you very much!