# tmpFile.renameTo(classFile) failed error

Tags: java, jsp, jboss, tiles

Getting following exception while deploying a EAR on Jboss 5.1

```
java.io.IOException: tmpFile.renameTo(classFile) failed
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.SmapUtil$SDEInstaller.install(SmapUtil.java:246)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.SmapUtil.installSmap(SmapUtil.java:165)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:454)
```

this looks related to this [bug](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=38713). Seems like JSP compiler is not able to write the compiled file but ***this error occurs only for a particular page and not for all JSPs***.

After googling and searching on SO I tried following things
1. Checked disk space (80+ Gbs are available)
2. Checked folder write access (Gave full control to all users on jboos folder/tmp/work and deploy)
3. Updated `fork` parameter in web.xml to true (`C:\jboss-eap-5.1\jboss-as\server\default\deployers\jbossweb.deployer\web.xml`)
4. made sure that the JSP is not open in any other aaplication.
5. tried restarting/replacing Jboss.
6. Tried with better net (some people said it occuers on slow net connection)
7. Also checked that indexing is disabled in `web.xml`

Further details  :
OS: Windows 7 (64 bit)

Complete stacktrace

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.apache.tiles.impl.CannotRenderException: JSPException including path '/WEB-INF/view/user/general/dashboard/show.jsp'.
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:656)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:368)
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:97)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:78)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.java:89)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:79)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:169)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
root cause

org.apache.tiles.impl.CannotRenderException: JSPException including path '/WEB-INF/view/user/general/dashboard/show.jsp'.
org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:692)
org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:644)
org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:627)
org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:321)
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView.renderMergedOutputModel(TilesView.java:124)
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:250)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1047)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:817)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:368)
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:97)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:78)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.java:89)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:79)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:169)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
root cause

org.apache.tiles.util.TilesIOException: JSPException including path '/WEB-INF/view/user/general/dashboard/show.jsp'.
org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletUtil.wrapServletException(ServletUtil.java:241)
org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.include(JspTilesRequestContext.java:105)
org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.dispatch(JspTilesRequestContext.java:96)
org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.TemplateAttributeRenderer.write(TemplateAttributeRenderer.java:44)
org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.render(AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.java:106)
org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.ChainedDelegateAttributeRenderer.write(ChainedDelegateAttributeRenderer.java:76)
org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.render(AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.java:106)
org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:670)
org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:336)
org.apache.tiles.template.InsertAttributeModel.renderAttribute(InsertAttributeModel.java:210)
org.apache.tiles.template.InsertAttributeModel.end(InsertAttributeModel.java:126)
org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag.doTag(InsertAttributeTag.java:311)
org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.view.TilesLayoutOnline_jsp._jspx_meth_tiles_005finsertAttribute_005f2(TilesLayoutOnline_jsp.java:527)
org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.view.TilesLayoutOnline_jsp._jspService(TilesLayoutOnline_jsp.java:201)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:369)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:322)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:249)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.forward(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:241)
org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.dispatch(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:222)
org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.TemplateAttributeRenderer.write(TemplateAttributeRenderer.java:44)
org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.render(AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.java:106)
org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:670)
org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:690)
org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:644)
org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:627)
org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:321)
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView.renderMergedOutputModel(TilesView.java:124)
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:250)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1047)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:817)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:368)
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:97)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:78)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.java:89)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:79)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:169)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
root cause

java.io.IOException: tmpFile.renameTo(classFile) failed
org.apache.jasper.compiler.SmapUtil$SDEInstaller.install(SmapUtil.java:246)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.SmapUtil.installSmap(SmapUtil.java:165)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:454)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:335)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:313)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:300)
org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:585)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:312)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:322)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:249)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:968)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doInclude(PageContextImpl.java:640)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.include(PageContextImpl.java:634)
org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.include(JspTilesRequestContext.java:103)
org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.dispatch(JspTilesRequestContext.java:96)
org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.TemplateAttributeRenderer.write(TemplateAttributeRenderer.java:44)
org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.render(AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.java:106)
org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.ChainedDelegateAttributeRenderer.write(ChainedDelegateAttributeRenderer.java:76)
org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.render(AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.java:106)
org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:670)
org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:336)
org.apache.tiles.template.InsertAttributeModel.renderAttribute(InsertAttributeModel.java:210)
org.apache.tiles.template.InsertAttributeModel.end(InsertAttributeModel.java:126)
org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag.doTag(InsertAttributeTag.java:311)
org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.view.TilesLayoutOnline_jsp._jspx_meth_tiles_005finsertAttribute_005f2(TilesLayoutOnline_jsp.java:527)
org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.view.TilesLayoutOnline_jsp._jspService(TilesLayoutOnline_jsp.java:201)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:369)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:322)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:249)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.forward(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:241)
org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.dispatch(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:222)
org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.TemplateAttributeRenderer.write(TemplateAttributeRenderer.java:44)
org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.render(AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.java:106)
org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:670)
org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:690)
org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:644)
org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:627)
org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:321)
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView.renderMergedOutputModel(TilesView.java:124)
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:250)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1047)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:817)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:368)
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:97)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:78)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.java:89)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:79)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:169)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
```

Tried every solution mentioned in bug and related SO questions but no luck.

**EDIT :**
This exception occurs only on my laptop and that too on random JSPs. Project works fine on some other machines. So looks like to be a machine specific issue rather than coding issue in JSP

Comment: It should be possible to debug this quiz in IDE with appropriate sources.

Comment: @Vadzim: Not sure how to debug JSPs. Tile particularly. Can you share something?

Comment: It would be usual debug of JBoss code that does jsp compilation, not debug of jsp code. I've added some links in the answer.

Comment: @Vadzim: yes. was thinkign about debugging JSP

Answer (score 3):

Have you checked if your laptop has any firewall running? Not sure if you have already read this post, some people here had exactly the same problem as yours and they resolved it by turning off the McAffee:
http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/31614119?_19_threadView=tree

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you have temp files that cannot be removed by the deployment.
try stopping the server and deleting the folder/tmp/ folder manually and redeploy.

Comment: What is the size of the file? have you tried deploying the jsp incrementally? Cut the stuff in the body and try adding code as the deployment works until you have figured out that hidden error.

Comment: Actually this project works fine on other machine and I get this error on my laptop only. Also this error occurs on random JSPs so dont think its a JSP issue

Answer (score 1):

Some links that may be helpful for debugging this quiz.

[JBoss debugging in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/516196/jboss-debugging-in-eclipse)

[Debug JBoss source code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7272459/debug-jboss-source-code)

The place for breakpoint in the source:
http://grepcode.com/file/repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/org.jboss.web/jbossweb/3.0.0-CR1/org/apache/jasper/compiler/SmapUtil.java#246

Comment: Will give a try. But not sure if its a JSP issue as its random and occurs on particular machine only

Comment: There's also an option to switch jasper version as described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6780639/how-to-change-tomcat-compiler.

Comment: Couldnt see how its related to the issue.

Comment: Couldn't find the exact issue still awarding bounty for providing some directions. Thanks!